# Select date from jQuery calendar and display the date of the following saturday in a textbox

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I'd like to use the jquery calendar control to populate a date into an asp.net textbox.

When the user selects a date I want the date populated in the textbox to be only Saturday dates.  So if the day they select is not a Saturday I want the date of the next Saturday after the date the selected.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to achieve this in jquery. In that case you should handle the [onselect event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) to analyse what date has been selected and change the selection using the [setDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate) method. You may also want to add some server side validation to check that the final date is always a Saturday.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't have to be done in jquery. I just like the way their calendar control looks.

Comment: Well my point was that you could just do this entirely at the server side and redisplay the change to the user. Doing it client side with jquery is certainly the better choice.